# Convert Date Time Format MM/DD/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I am getting the date in mm/dd/yyyy and I want to convert it to DateTime dd/mm/yyyy. When I am using below code to convert the same,

Code:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '08/14/2022', 103)
```

I am getting an error which says:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How to convert this into date format?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles)? `103` isn't `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: I want to convert incoming mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy which is nothing but 103

Comment: In the above you are converting a `varchar` to a `datetime` and are defining your `varchar` to be in style `103` (`dd/MM/yyyy`), as a it result is fails as there aren't 14 months in a year. The real question is why are you using a `varchar` for date and time values and date and time data type?

Comment: Dates in SQL (and most databases) have no format, they're binary values. Where does this string come from? A table column? A client application? It's *far* better, easier and faster to use a `date`-related type instead of trying to guess and parse strings with arbitrary formats

Comment: because this is the input value to my store procedure. And its the business logic.

Comment: You can't assume that the *strings* will always use the format used by only 4% of the world's population. The only unambiguous date string formats are `YYYY-MM-DD` for `date`, `datetime2`, and `datetimeoffset` types and `YYYYMMDD` for all date types. Anything else depends on the locale of the string's producer.

Comment: @KunalRelan it's not business logic, it's a nasty coding bug. No business user asked `Make a stored procedure that will produce a bad date in 96% of cases`. The stored procedure can be fixed. Change the stored procedure's type to `date` instead of `varchar`. After that, it becomes the caller's problem to send proper dates, not yours

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: To understand just how nasty and serious the bug is, read [The Spanish family wrongly accused of child pornography due to a mistake reading a date](https://english.elpais.com/spanish_news/2020-09-08/the-spanish-family-wrongly-accused-of-child-pornography-due-to-a-mistake-reading-a-date.html). What you're trying to do right now is *intentionally* produce and store bad dates. Intentionally, because the bug is well known and so are the easy fixes.

Comment: *"And its the business logic."* this isn't a reason, it's a poor man's excuse to do something *wrong*. The business doesn't dictate what data type data should be stored in, because the business knows *nothing* about data types. It's not "business logic" that the date `10/14/2022` is ***before*** `12/04/1953` so why implement it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos believe it or not this what is the case. I know I can change the procedure, but what is the point of having this portal. I want to know is there any way I can the date format from varchar.

Comment: @KunalRelan no it's not. It's your assumption. Business users will never tell you to store bad data that will cause them financial loses and big fines. `what is the point of having this portal.` to give *good* answers, not just hack something that will end up harming people.

Comment: As for `is there any way I can the date format from varchar` you used the wrong format. Larnu's first comment links to the correct format. You already encountered the bug everyone is warning you about.

Comment: In truth, I don't doubt for a second, that the "business logic" was something like *"Dates should be in the format MM/dd/yyyy"*, or something to that effect, and this has been interpreted (by the OP, or someone else making terrible mistakes) as "Dates should be stored in the format MM/dd/yyyy"; these are **not** the same. How a date (and time) value is *presented* to a user and how they stored are *completely* different. Date (and time) data should be stored in a date (and time) data type. How Date (and time) values are *displayed* is controlled in the Presentation layer, *not* SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your value from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy :

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME, '08/14/2022', 101),103)
```

If you only want a datetime :

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '08/14/2022', 101)
```

Based on [this documentation](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)